# Qlikview - bar chart with multiple dimensions

Tags: expression, dimensions, qlikview

I have straight table with lot of data...

[image]

I need to create bar chart from this table - dimension to be year and expressions Column(1)-Column(2).

```
  column(1) = sum(Saldo)
  column(2) = sum(Saldo)/3
```

I try to set dimension to be year and expresion

```
sum(sum(Saldo) - (sum(Saldo)/3))
```

but I don't get same total like I get sum of rows of Column(1)-Column(2).

This is because I need to include in dimension Line.

How can I create bar chart with dimensions I have in straight table...?

Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand the issue. I've mocked up the same data and get the totals I'd expect... Could you perhaps show the result that you get in the bar chart? If you enable fast change on the bar chart then sometimes this helps diagnose an issue - you can switch between the bar chart and the straight table easily then.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `AGGR` function:

```
sum(aggr(sum(Saldo) - (sum(Saldo)/3),Document,Line,Item,Unit))
```

or just use plain math:

```
Sum(Saldo * (2/3)) or Sum(Saldo)*(2/3)
```